# Can a block rule on PF add the src ip to a table

Tags: freebsd, firewall, pf

So on iptables I can make deny rules act as honey pots by adding ip's that hit the rules to a list that another rule is used to block all traffic from.

I am trying to achieve the same thing on PF, but the only way I can find to add ip's to a table is using the overload function for rate limiting allow rules which is not what I want.